# what is the correct html code for aligning two lines of text, when the second line uses a span element?

Tags: html, css, text-formatting

I am attempting to format two lines of text using html code. These are for use in a WP metaslider caption describing an artwork.

The first line of text is a straightforward title.

The second line of text is divided into two parts:

- a centered description of the medium used,
- photo credits, floated right in a smaller font, so apart from the rest of the text but on this same second line because I need to save space.

I have used span to separate these two parts of text on this second line.

This very nearly works, however the text on the first line and the text in the first part of the second line are not centered in relation to each other.

Here is the code:

```
<p style="text-align: center; font-family: LATO; font-size: 12px;">« L'oiseau »
<p style="text-align: center; font-family: LATO; font-size: 10px;">Pierre calcaire
<span style="float: right; font-family: LATO; font-size: 7px;">Photo : Peter Pan</span>
</p>
```

I found a workaround by adding a text-indent of -70px to the first part of the second line, but since I have many slides with similar caption formats I need a cleaner method.

I can add css to my stylesheet if necessary.

Many thanks for your time,

Polly

Answer (score 0):

Use line height on the containing P tag.

```html
<p style="text-align: center; font-family: LATO; font-size: 12px;">« L'oiseau »
<p style="text-align: center; font-family: LATO; font-size: 10px; line-height: 16px">Pierre calcaire
<span style="float: right; font-family: LATO; font-size: 7px;">Photo : Peter Pan</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Changing the line height didn't do what I needed. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

You could make that containing paragraph have position relative on it and the span have absolute to the right:

```
<p style="text-align: center; font-family: LATO; font-size: 12px;">« L'oiseau »
<p style="text-align: center; font-family: LATO; font-size: 10px; position: relative;">Pierre calcaire
<span style="font-family: LATO; font-size: 7px; position: absolute; right: 0px;">Photo : Peter Pan</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Brilliant glad it helped! Don't forget to mark your question as answered :)